# PHP's IF and ELSE at one time

Tags: php

A code with the missing condition in the statement if:

```
if ( ... ) {
    echo 'BBB';
}
else {
    echo 'AAA';
}
```

Question: What should I write in a missed condition that the output of this code was a line:
AAABBB

Comment: Nothing. As written, *exactly one* of the branches will always be taken.

Comment: I swear I'm never going to write a single line of PHP code again if there is an answer to this question...

Comment: Congrats, Raphael, you have a reason for switching to a decent language.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker To be fair, C also allows this construct.

Comment: Yes, but Raphael didn't promise to quit C :)

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head:

```
if ( print('AAA') ) {
    echo 'BBB';
}
else {
    echo 'AAA';
}
```

but idk if this is valid PHP. :)

THX for the hint @Xeon06

Comment: echo is a language construct. it has no return value.

Comment: Would work with `print`.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zuKjlg

Comment: echo/printf issue aside, what was the purpose of `true &&`? I would understand `|| true`, but `true &&`?

Comment: (and no, downvote is not mine:))

Comment: the && was a typo, it was supposed to be || and that's because I didn't know what echo returns (apparently it doesn't even return)

Comment: Luchian, Neither I am the php developer and I didn't steal your answer, you just typed it faster, because I went to *check* if echo can be used in this context. And I just asked what was your intent when writing the construct, it wasn't meant as offense.

Comment: I see now. Then you should've made it `||true`, otherwise the expression after `true||` wouldn't be evaluated.

Comment: @Michael okay sorry I missunderstood. Sorry again.

Comment: No problem, you might have had a bad day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. An if() statement is EITHER/OR. You cannot execute both the TRUE and the FALSE branches of an if statement at the same time. If you do need both branches to execute, then don't use an if():

```
echo 'AAA';
echo 'BBB';
```

Comment: Who's the bonehead giving down votes in here to correct answers to a non-question?

Comment: Man, if you read the line starting with "Question:" carefully, you'd realize that you have given no answer whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( printf("AAA") ) {
    echo 'BBB';
}
else {
    echo 'AAA';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One has to be true or not. It can't be both true and false. However, this can be done with an if-else statement.